# How to integrate IIB with AS\400 database?

Tags: odbc, ibm-midrange, db2-400, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

I am trying to connect IIB to IBM Iseries Database (DB2), but unfortunately I am not able to find the proper way to do this I tried to modify odbc.ini file as below:

```
Driver=/users/pc901/ODBC6.0/lib/DWdb224.so
Description=DataDirect 6.0 DB2 Wire Protocol
ApplicationUsingThreads=1
AuthenticationMethod=0
BulkBinaryThreshold=32
BulkCharacterThreshold=-1
BulkLoadBatchSize=1024
CharsetFor65535=0
Collection=DB2DEV
ConnectionReset=0
ConnectionRetryCount=0
ConnectionRetryDelay=3
Database=
DefaultIsolationLevel=1
DynamicSections=200
EnableBulkLoad=0
EncryptionMethod=0
FailoverGranularity=0
FailoverMode=0
FailoverPreconnect=0
GrantAuthid=PUBLIC
GrantExecute=1
GSSClient=native
IpAddress=DB2.IBM.NET
LoadBalanceTimeout=0
LoadBalancing=0
Location=DB2LOC
MaxPoolSize=100
MinPoolSize=0
PackageCollection=NULLID
PackageNamePrefix=DD
Pooling=0
QueryTimeout=0
ReportCodePageConversionErrors=0
TcpPort=999
UseCurrentSchema=1
ValidateServerCertificate=1
WithHold=1
XMLDescribeType=-10
```

then I run the mqsisetdbparms then restart the integration node after this I run mqsicvp command and the following error appears

```
    BIP2322E: Database error: SQL State ''08001''; Native Error Code '-1013'; Error Text ''[unixODBC][IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1013N  The database alias name or database name "DEV" could not be found.  SQLSTATE=42705 ''.
```

Comment: First, AS/400 is written with a slash, not backslash. Second, please provide the steps you already tried. This is no place to get advice for free without you proving to actually have tried to solve your problem.

Comment: Not sure how you got all those parameters, but it seems to me you don't have your DB2 client set up. You need to add the remote DB2 instance in your client. A quote from the knowledge center page for setting up DB2 connections: "In Database, type the DB2 alias. The data source name must be the same as the database alias name. If you are using a remote DB2 database, you must set up your client/server connection to resolve this alias to the correct database. For more information, see the DB2 documentation."

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bk58060_.htm

Comment: Is this a DB2 for i driver or a DB2 LUW driver? They are different enough to not be interchangeable.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not using the correct driver. There are 3 flavors of DB2, and the drivers are not interchangeable. If you are trying to connect to DB2 for i, which is indicated by the ibm-midrange tag, then you need the ODBC driver from i Access Client Solutions. There are both windows and Linux drivers. This is licensed software, and you will need a valid license for the box you are trying to connect to. Here is a link to the product web site: [IBM i Access Overview](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-i-access-overview)

If you cannot get a copy of that driver, then it looks like you can use JDBC with IIB as well. You can find an appropriate JDBC driver on Source Forge [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400/).